# Xcode iPad resolution in landscape mode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I`m new at iOS development. I have seen that the new iPad 3 have an 1536x2048 resolution. And I asked from my designer that all the design should be in that resolution, but now i see that i have to resize every image, button and background to fit xcodes story board. How in xcode i can set the development resolution to 1536*2048?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. Xcode uses points to reference pixels and automatically uses the correct graphics depending on the device. You have to make two copies of your image, "image" and "image@2x".

You do all of your development with "image" and iOS will automatically use the @2x version if the device is retina.

Comment: Close, if you use `image.png`, `image.png` will be used on retina and non-retina devices. The OP would need to use `image` to have iOS automatically select the retina/non-retina image.

Answer (score 2):

Your HD images should have `@2x` suffix. See "Specifying High-Resolution Images in iOS" section of [Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html),

Answer (score 1):

1536x2048 is the resolution of the screen (in pixel) but in xcode you are working with points. So ipad3 has still 1024x786 points (the same as in ipad2) but you can go to the point 0.5 for example.